# make enter button clickable?

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` box and when you click it the soft keyboard comes up as usual, but how do make it so that when the enter button gets pressed it performs a action like your pushing enter, search, or go?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
editTextBox.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {

                //Code here
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```